# assigning numerical values to variable

Tags: import, assignment, variable

I have a csv data file, has two columns of data. First column denotes time (t) and the corresponding value in the second column is flow rate (f). I would like to assign these values to an array f[t], to use in numerical solution of a differential equation (`NDSolve[ ]`).

Thanks and Regards

Comment: `Interpolation[data]`? Assumes `data` is in the form `{{t1, f1}, {t2, f2},...}`.

Comment: yes, exactly in this form, {{t1, f1}, {t2, f2},...}

Comment: Do not forget to first import it: `data=Import["FullPathToTheFile.csv"]` and then use the advice of Michael.

Comment: Thank you Michael E2 for the suggestions....It worked...

Comment: @Anand do you want to post your own complete solution is a way that could help other people? As you receive **you can give back**! As you gain reputation you can vote and answer questions. Keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.